# Low rank approximation

Tags: references, density-function, matrix, approximation

I'm looking for literature that deals with the following problem (does anybody know any paper related to it).

The Low-Rank Approximation problem is well known:

$$\min \|X - \hat{X}\|_{F}, \: \text{s.t.}\ rank(X) \leq K $$

Given matrix $\hat{X}$ we try to find a matrix $X$ that approximates $\hat{X}$ with the lowest possible rank.

More restrictions can be imposed on the solution. For example, the Structured Low-Rank Approximation problem, impose an additionally restriction on the structure of $X$: Toeplitz, Sylvester, Hankel.

My question is:

Do you know if there is any way to solve the same problem by imposing a given probability density to the entries of the matrix?

Comment: Singular Value Decomposition is one tool to find a low rank approximation to a matrix wrt Frobenius norm. Assigning probability part I didn't quite understand as I am assuming you already have the matrix at hand, which gives you the information you need without any uncertainty.

Comment: SVD is the optimal solution for the case where there are no restrictions imposed on matrix $X$ (as far as I know). The point of assigning probability to the entries of the matrix (if it makes sense at the end) is to be able to 'fit' a probability density to the empirical entries of the given matrix $\hat{X}$. That is to say, the lowest rank problem provides a way of approximating $\hat{X}$ with a lower rank, but if on top of that one be able to restrict the solution so it behaves as following a desired pdf, that would be the goal.